# how displaying server information in Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to write a program to retrieve information from the server and display it in the Recycler View,But I have two problems.

1. When I add data to the table it will be added to the Recycler View list But when I delete, the list doesn't change.

2.Photos of each section cannot be loaded.

home.java

```
       public class Home extends Fragment {


    public Home() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    SwipeRefreshLayout srl;
    RecyclerView rv;
    FloatingActionButton add;
    ArrayList<Post> al;
    PostAdapter pa;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        srl = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.srl);
        rv = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rv);
      //  add = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.add);

        AndroidNetworking.initialize(getContext());

        al = new ArrayList<>();
        pa = new PostAdapter(getContext(),al);

        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        rv.setAdapter(pa);

        update();

        srl.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                update();
            }
        });


    }
    private void update(){
        String id = al.size() == 0 ? "0" : al.get(0).getId();

        AndroidNetworking.post(Urls.host+Urls.post)
                .addBodyParameter("id",id)
                .build()
                .getAsObjectList(Post.class, new ParsedRequestListener<List<Post>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(List<Post> response) {
                        srl.setRefreshing(false);
                        for (Post p : response){
                            al.add(0,p);
                            pa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError anError) {
                        srl.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                });


    }

}
```

---

postadapter.java

```
      public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Post> al;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public PostAdapter(Context ctx,ArrayList<Post> arl){
        context = ctx;
        al = arl;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item,null,false);

        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Post s = al.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(s.getTitle());
        holder.text.setText(s.getText());
        holder.date.setText(s.getDate());
        holder.image.setImageUrl(Urls.host+s.getImage());
        holder.image.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.material);
       holder.image.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.material);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return al.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ANImageView image;
        AppCompatTextView title, text, date;
        AppCompatImageView share;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);


        }
    }

}
```

---

post.java

```
      public class Post {
    String title,text, date,id;
    int imageUrl;
    public Post(int imageUrl, String title, String text, String time, String id) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.title = title;
        this.text = text;
        this.date = time;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImage(int imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<Post> al;
ArrayList<Post> newDataList;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public PostAdapter(Context ctx,ArrayList<Post> arl){
    context = ctx;
    al = arl;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item,null,false);

    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    view.setLayoutParams(lp);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Post s = al.get(position);

    holder.title.setText(s.getTitle());
    holder.text.setText(s.getText());
    holder.date.setText(s.getDate());
    holder.image.setImageUrl(Urls.host+s.getImage());
    holder.image.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.material);
   holder.image.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.material);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return al.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ANImageView image;
    AppCompatTextView title, text, date;
    AppCompatImageView share;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);


    }


 public ArrayList<Post> getDataSet() {
        return al;
    }

   public void refresh(ArrayList<Post> list) {
        newDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        newDataList.addAll(list);
        al.clear();
        al.addAll(newDataList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

Now at time when you wants to add or delete try getting adapter.getDataSet()
and update list with adapter.refresh(yourList)

Comment: clarc  I added 'refresh' to the update function but the program could not be refreshed

Comment: you need to add both functions , getDataSet() and than update list .

Comment: srl.setRefreshing(false);
                    for (Post p : response){
                        al.add(0,p);
                        pa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
in this are you adding data at 0 position intentionally?